# setTimeout within 'while' causes a browser crash. How can I avoid it?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am new to coding and I want to built a Text Adeventure Game with HTML , CSS and Javascript. I want to show many peaces of text from an array with a certain time between each text. I tried different methods to avoid an infinite loop because of setTimeout, but I didn't figure out how to apply it on my code.

Here's my code, that causes the crash:

```
var iCounterText = 0;

var verzog = function() {
  document.getElementById('toggleText').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', '<br>--------------<br>');
  document.getElementById('toggleText').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', part1[iCounterText]);
  iCounterText = iCounterText + 1;
  playaudio();
}

function forwardingLinks() {
  while (iCounterText < part1.length - 1) {
    setTimeout(verzog, 500); // Here is the problem //
  }
  document.getElementById('buttonLinks').innerHTML = part1[part1.length - 1];
}
```

The following code works fine, but then there is no timeout between the text:

```
function forwardingLinks() {
  while (iCounterText < part1.length - 1) {
    verzog();
  }
  document.getElementById('buttonLinks').innerHTML = part1[part1.length - 1];
}
```

---

Edit:
This is my new code with "setInterval". Problem: Value is added by 1, but the function is not using the part2 Array. Instead it is using part1 Array again, although the partvalue already contains part2 array.

```
var part1 = [                          //Texte und Antworten
'Hallo?',
'Test?',
'What',
'hello',
'--------------',

'Was?'
];

var part2 = [                          //Texte und Antworten
'part2 goes on....',
'bla bla',
'blablabla'

];

var iCounterText = 0;                           
var value = 1;
var partvalue = eval("part" + value);

function forwardingLinks() { 
var verzog = setInterval(function(){
if(iCounterText < partvalue.length-2){
++iCounterText;
toggleText.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', '<br>--------------<br>');
toggleText.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', partvalue[iCounterText]);
playaudio();
}else{
    buttonLinks.innerHTML = partvalue[partvalue.length-1];
    ++value;
    iCounterText=0;
    clearInterval(verzog);

}
},500);
}
```

Comment: You're not changing `iCounterText` in the `while` loop, so how should the loop stop? You don't change it until the timeout function runs, but that won't happen until you get out of the loop.

Comment: Use `setInterval` to run your function every 500 ms. When the counter reaches the limit, it should call `clearInterval` to stop itself.

Comment: you could also try adding a transition timing on the added elements instead of a timeout

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the flow of your while loop. JavaScript runs in a single-threaded environment. That means that your calls to the `verzog` function won't run until the `forwardingLinks` function completes, but your `forwardingLinks` function won't ever complete because you have a while loop that is dependent on a counter that is never increased, because `verzog` hasn't run yet.

Change your `while` loop, so that the `iCounterText` variable gets incremented from within the loop, so the loop can end and then the calls to `verzog` that have stacked up in the event queue can start to run.

Additionally, since you are using a numeric counter, a regular `for` loop would be better than an `while` loop because the loop's step value (`++iCounterText`) is required:

```
 for(var iCounterText = 0; iCounterText < part1.length; ++iCounterText) {
   setTimeout(verzog, 500); 
 }
```

As an aside from your main problem, it is very inefficient to repeatedly scan the DOM for the same element over and over, as you are doing in your `verzog` function.  Instead, just get the DOM reference once and store it in a variable that can be reused:

```
 // Declare a variable in a scope that is accessible throughout your code
 var toggleText = null, buttonLinks = null;

 // Set up a callback that runs after the DOM is ready
 window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

      // Scan the DOM for the element(s) you'll be needing
      toggleText = document.getElementById('toggleText');
      buttonLinks = document.getElementById('buttonLinks');

 });

 function verzog() {
   // Now, you can just refer to the DOM element you've already found:
   toggleText .insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', '<br>--------------<br>');
   toggleText .insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', part1[iCounterText]);
   playaudio();
 }

 function forwardingLinks() {
    for(var iCounterText = 0; iCounterText < part1.length; ++iCounterText) {
      setTimeout(verzog, 500); 
    }

    // Now, you can just refer to the DOM element you've already found:
    buttonLinks.innerHTML = part1[part1.length - 1];
 }
```

Comment: thank you, I will try it today. Is it possible to avoid the ".insertAdjacentHTML" repitition? I guess there is no way to put a variable AND html-code into one function?

Comment: I edited my code, but now I get 6 times the first text of the array "part1" and there is no timeout between these texts. The function is stopping when  iCounterText  > part1.length, but the verzog() function does not work with the new iCounterText value. It always uses part1[0].

Comment: Can you post all the relevant code so we can see exactly what you are doing?

Comment: I added the code to #1. I tried "setInterval" now instead of "setTimeout".